# Hubot Hear Variable

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

I was hoping to find away to get hubot to here a variable.
Ex

```
name = "Peter"
module.exports = (robot) ->
   robot.hear /hello name/i, (msg) ->
       msg.send "Peter?! No I am Hubot."
```

I have already tried "#{}" syntax like below, but got nowhere with it.

```
name = "Peter"
module.exports = (robot) ->
   robot.hear /hello #{name}/i, (msg) ->
       msg.send "Peter?! No I am Hubot."
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Austin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your regex is not a constant, you should use [`new Regex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> Using the constructor function provides runtime compilation of the regular expression. Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.

**Code**

```
name = "Peter"
regx = new Regex("hello #{ name }", 'i')
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.hear regx, (msg) ->
      msg.send "Peter?! No I am Hubot."
```

**Edit**
With name as a parameter

```
module.exports = (robot, name) ->
  regx = new Regex("hello #{ name }", 'i')
  robot.hear regx, (msg) ->
      msg.send "#{ name }?! No I am Hubot."
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the problem is that the name will change several times throughout execution. That is my bad I should have provided a more clear and complete section of code. Thanks again!

Comment: It's not a problem, you can make the name a parameter, that would work the same. I'm adding a code example to my answer.

Comment: the regex worked, but it seems I have another issue with the way in which hubot works. Thanks for the awesome answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case its useful, a hubot example using javascript rather than coffeescript that also takes the option chosen and places it in another variable:

```
const options = 'now|later|never';
const regexOptions = new RegExp(`starting (${options})`, 'i');
robot.respond(regexOptions, (msg) => {
    // this will respond to:
    // hubot starting now
    // but not to:
    // hubot starting notAnOption
    const optionChosen = msg.match[1];
    msg.send(`option chosen: ${optionChosen}`);
});
```

I use this technique when I have dynamic lists that I can add or remove names into, that I then want to use within responses - it does require a quick reload of hubot when adding a name to a list used in a command of course.